# Getting this error when fetching items in flutter "Error Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast"

Tags: flutter, mobile, mobile-development

Getting this error when fetching items from API
"**Error Exception: type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast**"

```
class Services {
  static Future<List<Products>> getProducts() async {
    try {
      final response =
          await http.get(Uri.parse('http://67.205.140.117/api/products'));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        List<Products> list = parseProducts(response.body);

        return list;
      } else {
        throw Exception("Error");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception(e.toString());
    }
  }

  static List<Products> parseProducts(String responseBody) {
    List parsed = (json.decode(responseBody)).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    return parsed.map<Products>((json) => Products.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }
}
```

json response

```
[[{"id":1,"productname":"iPhone","description":"iPhone Xs Max","price":120000,"units":2,"images":"2022061331Untitled design (2).png","category":"1","created_at":"2022-06-07T13:31:25.000000Z","updated_at":"2022-06-07T13:31:25.000000Z"}],"Products Fetched"]
```

Comment: Can you also post the json response?

Comment: parsed should be Map<String, dynamic> not List, or simply use final keyword

Answer (score -1):

remove .cast<Map<String, dynamic>>(); and change the code to  List parsed = (json.decode(responseBody)as List);